# Ember upgrade to 3.27 TypeError: Ember.computed.alias is not a function

Tags: ember.js, upgrade, ember-cli

I'm upgrading a project from 3.26 to 3.27 using ember-cli-update, and then this error started happening, As I could see the error is raised when we try to access some method inside `@ember/computed` like `alias`. The first time the error occurred was [here](https://github.com/webark/ember-component-css/blob/master/addon/initializers/component-styles.js#L48)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I just commented the line to test and the same error occurred in another addon. So it's not related to the addon but something in the project

Comment: do you happen to have ember-computed-macros somewhere in your dependency tree? that addon does dirty things like monkey patch global objects and I've seen it be the cause of this -- I'd get rid of that addon if you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible that this is a version related problem, but I have no advanced knowledge of the history of Ember and just discover it.

You may use the feature as a free function like this:

```js
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

const Shirt = Ember.Object.extend({
   colour: 'white',
   color: alias('colour'),
});
```